¿Cómo puedo crear Web Components (custom elements) en Nuxt.js que puedan ser utilizados en otros websites?
Me gustaría saber cómo puedo crear un componente de Vue en Nuxt y luego poder volverlo un custom element para que pueda ser utilizado de la siguiente manera en otros websites:
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Web Component generado -->
  <script src="https://my-domain.com/custom-element.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Usar el Web Component -->
  <custom-element custom-prop="custom-value"></custom-element>
</body>
</html>

Sé que para registrarlo el código es el siguiente (desde un plugin en este caso):
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue';
import CustomElement from '~/components/CustomElement.vue';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((_) => {
  const MyCustomElement = defineCustomElement(CustomElement);

  customElements.define('my-custom-element', MyCustomElement);
});

Pero luego de ahí no sé como puedo generar o compilar un script al cuál se pueda hacer referencia en otro website y utilizar el web component. He intentado algunas configuraciones en el archivo nuxt.config.ts pero no he logrado conseguir el resultado esperado.
